# Making a pull request from TeamCity

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

We are trying to configure TeamCity to make a Github pull request on build run. The pull request should be made without merging.

For example, we have a hotfix branch and after hotfix is pushed there, we want to make a pull request to develop branch without merging. As the pull request needs to be reviewed and some files may need updates.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your VCS, you just need to specify in your branch configuration:
`+:refs/pull/*/merge` if you want to test the result of the pull request; integrated with the destination branch.

And, if you want to test the pull request itself, without the integration with the changes which has happened on the destination branch, you can set:
`+:refs/pull/*/head`

This will not do the merge at the end of your test, unless you add the specific feature:`automatic merge`.

Comment: Will it also merge it or just make a pull request?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test it later.